# Electron, HTML, displaying pictures

Tags: html, image, electron

I am working on an Electron-App.
In this app. I need to display .jpg-pictures and I must load these pictures from memory, not from URL. According to the standard HTML-documentation this can be done with the following statement:

<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,/9j/4RiDRXhpZgAATU0AKgA..."

However, I don't manage to make this working in Electron.
When I load the pictures from URL it works.
Example: <img src="HTS_color.jpg"

How can I load and display .jpg-pictures from memory in Electron / HTML ?